# How to fix "Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"

Tags: gtk

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I receive this error when I open some of the programs like gedit, qpdfview, libreoffice etc.. It is repeated twice in the command line like below:

```
Gtk-Message: 16:57:37.270: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 16:57:37.271: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
```

What can be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably you want to install the `packagekit-gtk3-module` package.

Answer (score 1):

[Gunnar Hjalmarsson's](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) suggestion in the comments to

> install the `packagekit-gtk3-module`

... worked for me.  Moving this to an answer as confirmation that it does work.

Comment: sudo apt-get -y install packagekit-gtk3-module